# Different height to slide using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I'm trying to develop an ads which is similar to Pushdown Ads. What I want to is the initial height is 90 pixels just to click 'SHOW' button, and after clicked the button, the ads will be expanded into 200 pixels. What I have done so far is here my codings.

HTML

```
<div id="adsBox">

    <div id="ads">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/16gkd5c.jpg" alt="ads"> </a>
        <a href="#" class="expandImage"> <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/b9hx60.gif" alt="ads">
    </div>

    <p> <a href="#" id="showLink" class="showAds">HIDE</a> </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ads {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    display:none;
}

#adsBox {
    text-align:right;
    color:black;
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

#adsBox a {
    color:#535353;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#adsBox a:hover {
    color:#4682b4;
}

#ads img {
    width:100%;
}

#showLink {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.hideLink {
    display:none;
}   

.expandImage {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $("#ads").slideToggle(1000);
    }, 1000);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showAds').click(function () {
            $('#ads').slideToggle(500);
            if ($(this).text() == 'HIDE') {
                $(this).text('SHOW');
            } else {
                $(this).text('HIDE');
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/6/). The problem is how to make the height of ads start from 90 pixels before slide down into 200 pixels in one second? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `animate` function in jQuery to change the height of the ad. Not sure if this is what you're after?  http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/11/

Comment: Hello, this is the right one I am after. But the problem I have 2 different images. 1 image is for 90px height and another image is for 200px height. I'm wondering how to hide the image of 200px at the beginning and will show the image only if we click SHOW button. (At the beginning, the screen will show only 90px height).

Comment: You can make the img as a background of an `a` tag, create 2 classes for it, one is for the 90px height img and the other one for the 200px height img. When clicking the button, you can toggle the class as well as animate the height of the tag to create a smooth animation. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/16/

Comment: Also, the size of the images has to match the size of container, in terms of ratio, so that it fits perfectly in that space.

Comment: Great! That works for me! Thanks for explaining in details :)

Comment: Hello, would you let me know how to set timeout to expand it automatically after 2 seconds? here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ewYc3/18/). This doesn't work. Any ideas? @vbn87

Comment: 2 seconds after the page loads or?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware: You're trying to show the full image (which has 90px of height), but you're limiting your div to only 400px width. You should try cropping the image or adding more width to #adsBox, because the div height is 90px from the beginning, but your image is keeping the proportions and it's only 37px.